# Log4j and hibernate sql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, log4j

Can someone tell me how to log all sql statements into a separate file?
Here's my property file:

```
    # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout, hibernate, sql

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/karq/proovikas.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#log hibernate
log4j.appender.hibernate = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.hibernate.File=/home/karq/hibernate.log
log4j.appender.hibernate.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.hibernate.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.hibernate.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.hibernate.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.com.karq.server = INFO, hibernate
log4j.category.org.hibernate = INFO, hibernate
log4j.category.org.hibernate.type = INFO, hibernate
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate=false
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.type=false
log4j.additivity.com.karq.server=false
#log hibernate
log4j.appender.sql = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.sql.File=/home/karq/sql.log
log4j.appender.sql.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.sql.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.sql.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sql.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL = INFO, sql
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
```

Comment: did you enable hibernate.show_sql ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set your logger to DEBUG or ALL:

```
log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL = ALL, sql
```

[Here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html) is some article that talks about it.

Answer (score 0):

New versions of log4j use a combination of loggers and appenders. Categories aren't recommended anymore. I use this in my applications to do just what you're asking.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG, org.hibernate
log4j.logger.Hibernate=DEBUG, org.hibernate

log4j.appender.org.hibernate=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.org.hibernate.DatePattern=-yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.org.hibernate.File=hibernate.log
log4j.appender.org.hibernate.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.org.hibernate.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```